# Send large amount of DATA via REST - Best Practices

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, large-data

How is a good way to send like 100,000 records over REST from one part of an application to another part of that application on another server.

I was thinking about sending PKEY data in one POST request and then populate each record via PUT in bulks. Still, I have no clear idea how to do proper do it.

There are 3 questions in place:

a) Is proposed method ok? What about best practices ?
b) It's good to do a post then put ?
c) It's ok to do it one per request (meaning 100,000 request) or check the data via content-length or ... what? :D

Thanks in advance.
Bart

Answer (score 2):

The "rest" way to do it is to issue separate requests, or batch requests containing multiple objects. However, you can look at streaming capabilities in WCF, serialize objects to the stream and read them (see this [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestWithStreams.aspx) or this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/27/streaming-large-content-from-a-wcf-restful-service.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, too much complicated for me right now. I will look into the issue later. :D